# Change frame programmatically with auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` with Auto Layout and I need to reduce the height when the `GADBannerView` appears at the bottom of the screen.

Unfortunately with Auto Layout it is impossible to modify the frame. The solution is to remove Auto Layout and set the frame manually. This is very dangerous because all my apps works fine on 3.5' and 4.0' displays and removing Auto Layout adds a new testing phase and more effort.

Is there a way to change the frame even if Auto Layout is enabled?

Comment: create an outlet for your constraint and change its value whenever your `GADBannerView` appear.

Comment: can you explain better with an example please ?

Comment: [How to update the constant height constraint of a UIView programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49776158/6822622)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Let your `UITableView` constraints to bottom layout is set to 0, make an `IBOutlet`. Now let your `GADBannerView` height is 40 so change your `outlet.constant = 40;` For more about how to make `IBOutlet` and change its value have a look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15744287/ios-autolayout-how-to-set-two-different-distances-between-views-depends-on-th) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086054/unable-to-make-outlet-connection-to-a-constraint-in-ib) hope this will help.

**Edit:** For those who seeking for example, follow these simple steps (Because this is accepted answer, I think it is worth to have an example. Credit to @manujmv for this example)

1. Create a height constraint for your view in your interface.
2. Then add an IBOutlet object in your class for this constraint. 
   For example:

   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint
   *heightConstraint;

Connect this object in your connection panel.

3. Then change the value of this constraint whenever you needed

   self.heightConstraint.constant = 40;

Comment: A bit late to the party, but adding `self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;` to your view would have probably removed the need for modifying constraint constants.

Comment: @JohnRogers comment is actually the correct answer !

Answer (score 41):

Rather than trying to change the frame of the view, add a height constraint using auto layout and reduce the value of this constraint. Do the below steps:

1. create a height constarint for your view in your interface.
2. Then add an IBOutlet object in your class for this constraint. for example,

   ```
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;
   ```

   Connect this object in your connection panel.
3. Then change the value of this constraint whenever you needed

   ```
    self.heightConstraint.constant = 40;
   ```

Answer (score 7):

One more thing, you have to call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded];` method once you changne the constraints.

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2):

You can find out constraint like that

```
extension UIView {
    var heightConstaint: NSLayoutConstraint? {
        get {
            for constraint: NSLayoutConstraint in constraints {
                if constraint.firstAttribute == .height {
                    if constraint.relation == .equal {
                        return constraint
                    }
                }
            }
            return nil
        }

        set{
            setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
}
```