# Changing UIView (UIImageView specifically) frame programmatically not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiimageview

I load a `UIImageView` with a certain height and width. after I initialise it, I would like to change it's `height` programmatically. I am using the following code to do so, but it is not working.

Note: The `UIImageView` has constraints set on it.

```
CGRect newframe = imageView.frame;
newframe.size.height= 500;
[imageView setFrame:newframe];
```

Calling `setFrame` is not changing anything on the image. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: where are you changing the frame. in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Why are you changing the frame instead of using autolayout constraints?

Comment: Okay I will try to change the constraint. I am new to layout. Thanks

Comment: Autolayout "prevents" you from chaning frame like this. If you want this to work, you have to turn autolayout off :-)

Answer (score 1):

Modify the height constraint after initializing your UIImageView instead. See the second answer here for an example: [Change frame programmatically with auto layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655096/change-frame-programmatically-with-auto-layout)

Comment: One question, How do I connect an IBOutlet of a constraint to the class using Xcode?

Comment: The same way you connect your UIImageView to an IBOutlet.

Comment: My constraint is an aspect ratio. I am trying to access height. constraint.constant=0 is not working. I guess it will be something like constraint.secondItem.(something)=0 , what is that something?

Comment: @Pacemaker aspect ratio doesn't have a height. It has a relationship between width and height.