# Why can't I change the view's frame size in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, frame

So this is the weirdest thing I came across ever.

I add a simple `UIView` on top of an `UIView` on an `UIViewController`. I change the size to 200 x 200 and then I want to change the `UIView`'s size by placing this line of code inside the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
self.gameBackgroundView.frame.size.height = 10
```

which seems perfectly normal in Swift. Though, nothing happens. I can change the color, corner radius etc...

EDIT:

I have also deleted all constraints from that view and it still does not work.

Comment: Two things. I remember in Obj-C you had to change the whole frame property to get the view to update. The other thing is if you have Autolayout constraints set it'll ignore frame changes.

Comment: I have set like 4 constraints on another UIView though, does this apply on my other why which frame I want to change ?

Comment: Can you show how you create the view and add it as a subview?

Comment: I open my storyboard, drag a new UIView on top of my UIViewController, change the background color so I can see the frame changes and I create an IBOutlet in the corresponding class file

Comment: If you don't set constraints in InterfaceBuilder some will be added automatically. Check out `gameViewBuilder.constraints`. Also make sure `gameViewBuilder.translatesAutoResizingMaskToConstraints` is true.

Comment: when I print it out I can see only `[] []`

Comment: Yes I agree with @Tobias. setting the gameViewBuilder.translatesAutoResizingMaskToConstraints to true.  I was modifying the .frames() but it didn't work because I set the translatesAutoResizingMaskToConstraints to false.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok, So I found a solution here on stack ..

[Change frame programmatically with auto layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655096/change-frame-programmatically-with-auto-layout)

The correct answer, that works is, that:

1. I need to create an IBOutlet of my heightConstraint
2. Change the value of that constraint accordingly

Thank you all!

Answer (score 5):

It is because of Auto Layout, however, you could do it after Auto Layout is done its work or change constraints of it. Set it your `frame` in your `viewDidAppear()` instead. It should work.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: changing frame in auto layout will not help, it will reset once layout subivews is called. Instead change the constraint

Comment: I have no constraints set on that view, but I have another view above that but I don't think that has to do anything with it

Answer (score 4):

Try this code, it will work on any device

```
let BackImage = UIImage(named: "backGrndImg@2x.png")!

var imageView: UIImageView!

override func loadView() {

    super.loadView()
    self.imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectZero)
    self.imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    self.imageView.image = BackImage
    self.view.insertSubview(imageView, atIndex: 0)

}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.imageView.frame = self.view.bounds

}
```