# Resize the height of the tableview dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to resize the height of tableview ?
I can achieve ,when the screen is initially loaded. 
But when we  add data in add screen . we traverse from add screen to display screen. Height of the tableview not reflected. when I close the application and reopened the height get changed.
Only the height of tableview is not reflected.But the data got reflected.

```
 func tableSize(count:Int,tableView:UITableView) {
        switch count {
            case 0:
                    tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
            case 1:
                    tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 95).isActive = true
            case 2:
                    tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 115).isActive = true
            case 3:
                    tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 155).isActive = true
            case 4:
                    tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
            default:
                    tableView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true
        }
        tableView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        tableView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

    }
```

Comment: Is there something under the tableView? Or why do you want it to change its height?

Comment: Yes, I have 3 tableview.Based upon the row(s).I will change the height of the tableview

Comment: why don't you use a single tableView with 3 sections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, doing this you are not updating the constraint; only adding new ones.

You should declare a NSLayoutConstraint variable in your view controller, assign it the tableView's height constraint,  then update it's constant whenever you need to, before finally calling view.layoutIfNeeded()

See [How to update the constant height constraint of a uiview programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669554/how-to-update-the-constant-height-constraint-of-a-uiview-programatically)