# How can I change certain constraint parameters with programmatically?

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints

Can I change "top space to" constraint, equals parameter with programmatically?

Top Space to Equals is 15 in photo. Can I change this with 100?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update the constant height constraint of a UIView programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669554/how-to-update-the-constant-height-constraint-of-a-uiview-programatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, connect the constraint to an outlet like:

```
@IBOutlet var constraintTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Select the constraint in the storyboard and connect it as you would connect any other UI element.

1. Select `ViewController` and right-click drag to the constraint
   [image: 1]
2. Release click and select `contraintTop`
   [image: 2]

Then you can programmatically update it:

```
constraintTop.constant = 100
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

NOTE: Here `layoutIfNeeded()` is called on `self.view` because the constraint is owned by `self.view`.
In nested views, as an optimization, you could layout only the view that needs to be updated.
So suppose this constraint was in some other view, say `myView`, then you would do `myView.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: Solved. Thank you so much!