# editing autolayout "constant" attribute with equation in the stroybord inspector

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

is it possible to populate an equation in the "Constant" attribute located in the storyboard inspector , instead of a  direct constant
and if so, can you write me an example of doing so?

tnx ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update the constant height constraint of a UIView programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42669554/how-to-update-the-constant-height-constraint-of-a-uiview-programmatically)

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: What "equation" are you trying to use? It's possible that a combination of constraints with constants and/or multipliers can do what you need.

Comment: thank for the respone , Basically the "equation" can be something like that : "SuperView.Width/3" for an  "Equal Width" constraint . that means that the view, will be all ways third of its superview . I know that you can define it programatically, my question was about an more easy way to do it. how can a multipliers can help we get to the result of the view being alway 1/3 of its superview? , tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For basic constraint "equations" you can often use the multiplier.

For your specific example, *""SuperView.Width/3" for an "Equal Width" constraint"*, set the view's width equal to the superView's width, then enter either `0.33333` or `1:3` as the multiplier:

[image]

Now your subview will always be 1/3rd the width of its superView.