# moving subview - offset amount wrong, but visually correct?

Tags: swift

I wrote this sample program to try and figure out what is going on.  I have a textfield that upon clicking, shows a subview instead of showing a keyboard.  In the subview, there is a dismiss button which shifts the subview so the top aligns with the bottom of the screen.

Just so I can build the subview in storyboard, the subview is aligned to the bottom edge of the screen and `hidden` at startup.  `viewDidLoad` then calls the `hideSubView` to shift it offscreen before it starts.

I have `println` before and after each shift to tell me the position of the subview.

The problem I have is that the numbers don't add up.  I specifically tell swift to offset the Y by 210, but somehow it only shifts it by 68.5 which is *NOT* the bottom of the screen (note this is not done by setting the subview as an inputview of the textfield).  Yet when I click on the textfield, the subView animates from the bottom up, not some midway point.  Can anyone explain why either of these two things is happening?  One other thing is - where does the 457.0 for the initial minY come from?  I checked the initial height of the subview which strangely is 143 (not 141.5).

***Console Output (// - lines put in by me to clarify)***

```
//hideSubview called from viewDidLoad
Before. minY:457.0 screenheight:667.0 offset:210.0
After. minY:525.5 screenheight:667.0 offset:210.0  //NOTE:457+210 is 667, not 525.5
//1st showSubView called by clicking on myTextField
Before. minY:525.5 screenheight:667.0 subview Height:141.5
After. minY:525.5 subView height:141.5
//hideSubView called by clicking on dismiss button
Before. minY:525.5 screenheight:667.0 offset:141.5
After. minY:667.0 screenheight:667.0 offset:141.5 
//2nd showSubView called by clicking on myTextField
Before. minY:667.0 screenheight:667.0 subview Height:141.5
After. minY:525.5 subView height:141.5
//hideSubView called by clicking on dismiss button
Before. minY:525.5 screenheight:667.0 offset:141.5
After. minY:667.0 screenheight:667.0 offset:141.5
```

***Main.storyboard***
[image: screen capture of Storyboard]
***ViewController.swift***

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

  @IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var mySubView: UIView!

  var screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
  var subViewIsVisible = false


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myTextField.delegate = self
    hideSubView()
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }

  @IBAction func dismissButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    if subViewIsVisible {
      hideSubView()
    }
  }

  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    myTextField.endEditing(true)
    if !subViewIsVisible {
      showSubView()
    }
  }

  func hideSubView () {
    var offsetAmount = screenSize.height - mySubView.frame.minY
    println("Before. minY:\(mySubView.frame.minY) screenheight:\(screenSize.height) offset:\(offsetAmount)")
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut , animations:
      {
        self.mySubView.frame.offset(dx: 0, dy: offsetAmount)
      }, completion: {_ in
        self.subViewIsVisible = false
        self.mySubView.hidden = true
        println("After. minY:\(self.mySubView.frame.minY) screenheight:\(self.screenSize.height) offset:\(offsetAmount)")
      }
    )
  }

  func showSubView () {
    mySubView.hidden = false
    println("Before. minY:\(mySubView.frame.minY) screenheight:\(screenSize.height) subview Height:\(mySubView.frame.height)")
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut , animations:
      {
        self.mySubView.frame.offset(dx: 0, dy: -self.mySubView.frame.height)
      }, completion: {_ in
        self.subViewIsVisible = true
        println("After. minY:\(self.mySubView.frame.minY) subView height:\(self.mySubView.frame.height)")
      }
    )
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

***Constraints of mySubView:*** (easier to see than my comment for Bannings)
[image: Constraints on mySubView]

Comment: Why're you not assigning the `mySubView` to the `myTextField`'s `inputAccessoryView`?

Comment: @Bannings This is a simplified version of a program that I'm having issues with.  In that one, I have a `TextField` and a `Searchbar` that can both pull up `mySubView`.  My limited knowledge is that a view can have no more than 1 parent view.  In this example, if I set it as you say, then `mySubView` will have 2 parents - the main view where I drew it on the story board and the `TextField`.  Is this correct?

Comment: Did you add any constraints at your `mySubView`?

Comment: @Bannings ***External Constraints*** for `mySubView`:  1.  Align Center X to superview.  2. Leading Space to superview = 50. 3. Bottom Space = Bottom Layout Guide.  ***Internal Constraints*** (within the subview):  All 4 labels (Align Center X to Superview).  Top and Bottom of all 4 labels = 10.  So there is no explicit constraint on the subview to define it's precise height.  The height is defined by constrainst set on the internal components i.e. height of Dismiss button + L1+L2+L3 and 5x10 spaces.

Comment: I guess the 457 and the 143 comes from the inferred size as shown from `mySubView`'s Constraint screen capture.  However, I have set iOS simulator to iPhone6 so by the time viewDidLoad is running it should have all the right numbers.  Assuming the starting size is 143, I would expect autolayout to have placed `mySubView` at 667-143 = 524...

Answer (score 0):

The 457 and the 143 comes from your storyboard like this:

[image]

This behavior happens because the view's origin is incorrect in the `viewDidLoad` method. Although you had the bottom constraint with the `Bottom Layout Guide`, however, the frame hasn't been adjusted yet.

So, if you set the view's y to 500 then you getting a log as below:

[image]

```
Before. minY:500.0 screenheight:667.0 offset:167.0
After. minY:524.5 screenheight:667.0 offset:167.0
```

Your `mySubView`'s frame will be correct after `viewDidLoad` has been called by AutoLayout.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out.  But you do see the problem right?  There are multiple issues, but the most glaring, unresolved issue I have is:  In between those two `println`'s, there is a `self.mySubView.frame.offset(dx: 0, dy: offsetAmount)` (from hideSubView).  In your case, offset is 167. 500 + 167 is **NOT** 524.5.  Also note - 524.5 is NOT the bottom of the screen, but when you click on the textfield, the view will come up from the bottom where based on console output, it isn't at!

Comment: This is because you had  a `bottom constraint` that will cause its always on the screen. You can trying to comments the line `self.mySubView.hidden = true`

Comment: No matter what the value of this `offset` will not affect its position on the screen

Comment: I unchecked the "hidden" option for `mySubView` (in Storyboard) and commented out both `self.mySubView.hidden = true`.  When run, as you said, it is sitting on the bottom margin (essentially ignoring the hideSubView function I placed in viewDidLoad).  However, when you click on the textfield - which should animate the subview from it's current location to current-location minus subview's height, it comes from the bottom up as opposed to standing still since it is already in that location.

Comment: You can update its `frame` indeed, however that is unsafed, the Auto Layout will update its `frame` again in the next drawing update(e.g. rotate screen) so the result is not guaranteed. If you want to really to change it, you should make a IBOutlet, like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655096/change-frame-programmatically-with-auto-layout