# Xcode storyboard equivalent of Android LinearLayout with View.GONE

Tags: android, ios, xcode, storyboard, android-linearlayout

Basically, in Android I have a LinearLayout of 3 views on top of each other. If I set view 1 to 'View.GONE', view 2 becomes the top view and view 3 is still underneath it. Or if I set View 2 to 'View.GONE', View 1 is now above View 3. I cannot find any answers on how to do this in Xcode for an iOS app. I know there is UIStackView but that is iOS 9+ only, which I don't want. How do I do this? In Swift preferably.

Comment: There is autolayout. Did you look into it ?

Comment: How do I use AutoLayout to programmatically hide (removing space) and show (taking up space) views in a stack of views, for iOS 8, as asked in the question?

Comment: Setup the views as you need, and you need to make the view width/height constraints to 0, and the other views will adjust accordingly.

Comment: @Mr.T my views are constrained to where they are. If I set their height to 0, they still take up space.

Comment: No they dont. Waht kind of constraints did u apply ? Pls add the related information to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by pinning the views to the other views and then instead of trying to change the height of the view using an outlet of the view I created an outlet of the height constraint and set it to 0, as shown in this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23655322/4838107