# updating constraint value not working in auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have created the IBOutlet for the constraint of top spacing . I need to update the value that constraint programatically in viewDidLoad. Here is my declaration in IBOutlet :

```
 IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *labelTopSpace;
```

and here is how I changing the top:

```
labelTopSpace.constant = 50.0;
```

but this is not  working in my case . am I missing anything ?

**Update :** should I make the property of it ?

Comment: do drag and drop for outlet........make a proprty

Comment: try calling [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; or  [self.view updateConstraints]; after      assigning constant value.! Also check whether you have connected constraint at IB or not..

Comment: in `–viewDidLoad` you might not be able to update anything of UI efficiently, as then the view is not part of view hierarchy yet. you would be able to do it later, when it becomes part of a navigation stack or view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Make it property, like

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *labelTopSpace;
```

then check outlet connection. similarly asked question [Unable to make outlet connection to a constraint in IB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086054/unable-to-make-outlet-connection-to-a-constraint-in-ib)

Answer (score 0):

Hope, you have mentioned all the constraints under method!

```
- (void)updateViewConstraints
{
    [super updateViewConstraints];
    _labelTopSpace.constant = 50;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code..

```
[btn setConstraintConstant:50.0 forAttribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop];
```

you can replace the btn with any Ref which for which you have that Constraint that need to modified.{say self.view//if it is for view}

In this case you no need to create property or IBOulet reference to your Constraint..

You can Directly change as above..

Hope it is useful to you as alternate solution...!