# Xcode Obj-C - How do you change the width of a UIImageView as well as the UIImage inside of it

Tags: ios, objective-c, resize, uiimage

I have 3 `UIImageView` and each contains an `image`. I have an if statement that when triggered should change the `width` of the `image`.

I have tried:

```
relaxedV.frame = CGRectMake(0, 53, 320, 479);
relaxedV.frame = CGSizeMake(0, 53, 320, 479);
relaxedV.image = CGRectMake(0, 53, 320, 479);
relaxedV.image = CGSizeMake(0, 53, 320, 479);
```

and a few others but nothing works so far. How can I just change the `width`? Is there a better way to do this than using a `UIImageView`? The images are just solid colors so I could just have them drawn with code if someone could instruct me that too

Comment: Did you add the 'UIImageView' through storyboard or code?

Comment: CGSizeMake only takes (width, height) as arguments. Don't you mean: `CGSizeMake(320, 479)`

Comment: Your last 3 lines are incorrect. 

- frame cannot be set to CGSize.
- image cannot be set to CGRect.
- image cannot be set to CGSize.

Comment: @Max your problem is solved or not.??

Answer (score 1):

Here is the several cases.

1. You may using `AutoLayout`. In that case setting frames manually is discouraged, you should change the constraints instead. Read [here at the SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086054/unable-to-make-outlet-connection-to-a-constraint-in-ib) for further information
2. You may use `AutoresizingMask`. If it is set to adjust width to superview or something like that, it is also discouraged to break that rules. Instead reconsider your autoresizing mask settings
3. You do it manually. In that case, you may use the following code to change only the `width`:

Code:

```
CGRect relaxedVframe = relaxedV.frame;
relaxedVframe.size.width = newWidth;
relaxedV.frame = relaxedVframe;
```

You also mention that your images are only solid color, then I would like to recommend you the following approach:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

You may use that code to put solid-colored image to any sized `UIImageView`

Comment: You can also do:

`relaxedV.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(oldFrame), CGRectGetMinY(oldFrame), newWidth, CGRectGetHeight(oldFrame));`

Comment: @Azat You should probably return a resizableImage.

Comment: @Tobias it works perfectly even without that, because it is only a solid color and you cannot distinguish its pixellation. Anyway, thank you for the comment!

Comment: Yeah. I just like returning a resizableImage because it's ready for use on button backgrounds and other stretchable controls.

Comment: I tried that and the image width still does not change. Can you think of any reason why?

Comment: Don't you use neither `AutoLayout` nor `AutoresizingMask`?