# Access constraint in code, which was created in iOS Designer

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

In Interface Builder (Xcode) one can visually create a constraint and later add an outlet to access the constraint in code like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22110084/426227). Is something similar possible in iOS Designer (Xamarin Studio)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpler than thought. Select the constraint you want to change. With double click on the constraint you directly get to the settings of the constraints in the Properties Pad.

Enter a name for the constraint and now you can use that constraint in code.