# Swift - set height for UICollectionViewCell inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have created `UITableView` with multiple sections. Each section has one line (`UITableViewCell`) and inside this line, I have `UICollectionView` and inside it `UICollectionViewCell`. Scrolling is working correctly. However, when I change the table row height, `UICollectionView` height remain unchaged. How to fix this?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var tab: HorizontalSelector? = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var tabView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       tab = HorizontalSelector(frame: self.tabView.frame)

       tab?.addSection("Jedna", withHeight: 100)
       tab?.addSection("Middle", withHeight: 100)
       tab?.addSection("Dva", withHeight: 100)

        self.tabView.addSubview(tab!)
    }
}
```

Class for horizontal selector

```
class HorizontalSelector: UITableView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let CELL_REUSE_ID = "cellSectionRow"
    let DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT: CGFloat = 44

    var sectionHeights: [CGFloat] =  []
    var sections: [String] = []

    init(frame: CGRect){

        var f: CGRect = frame
        f.origin.x = 0
        f.origin.y = 0

        super.init(frame: f, style: UITableViewStyle.plain)

        self.initialize()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)

        self.initialize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")        
    }

    func initialize(){
        self.register(SectionCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: CELL_REUSE_ID)

        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    func addSection(_ section: String){
        sections.append(section)
        sectionHeights.append(DEFAULT_ROW_HEIGHT)
    }

    func addSection(_ section: String, withHeight: CGFloat){
        sections.append(section)
        sectionHeights.append(withHeight)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return sectionHeights[indexPath.section]
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sections[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let sectionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CELL_REUSE_ID) as! SectionCell

        sectionCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown

        return sectionCell
    }
}
```

Class for single table section

```
class SectionCell: UITableViewCell {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.initialize()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.initialize()
    }

    func initialize(){

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        self.contentView.addSubview(SectionCellRowCollection(frame: self.contentView.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout))
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Class for collection within single table section

```
class SectionCellRowCollection: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    private let COLLECTION_CELL_ID = "collectionCell"

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout){
        super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

        self.initialize()
    }

    private func initialize(){
        self.register(SectionCellRowCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: COLLECTION_CELL_ID)
        self.dataSource = self
        self.delegate = self

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 12
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: COLLECTION_CELL_ID, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SectionCellRowCollectionCell

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

        return cell

    }
}
```

Class for single cell inside colection

```
class SectionCellRowCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell{

    var imageView: UIImageView!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
         fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height*2/3))
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Swift-cover")
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup constraints for your collectionView and it will change its frame base on these constraints:

```
class SectionCell: UITableViewCell {
    private var collectionView: SectionCellRowCollection!

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        initialize()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        initialize()
    }

    private func initialize() {
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        collectionView = SectionCellRowCollection(frame: contentView.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.addSubview(collectionView)
        // constraints
        collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    }
}
```

Comment: Did not work... It will end with "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" and bunch of error outputs

Comment: Edited my answer. Also, after appending new row to your array don't forget to call `reloadData()`

Comment: Still the same error. Complete error output: https://pastebin.com/5A1DZT7e

Comment: My bad, missed one line `collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
`. Please, try again.

Answer (score 1):

You have collectionView inside the tableviewCell so there is some static height of collectionView in storyboard so whatever the height of tableview the collectionView takes its height as its not clip to bounds.So to resolve that problem you must give height of tableView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 100.0;//Choose your custom row height
}

Then set the collectionView cell height that must be cell or equal to tableview height 

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: screenWidth, height:90 );
}
```

Comment: This will set collectionViewCell size, but collectionView itself is still not height enough.

Comment: For that you need to either set collectionView Height constraint then create outlet of that constraint and then set the collection height constraint to whatever value 
Or
Set collectionView constraint like leading, trailing , top , bottom to UITableViewCell and then whatever height of UITableViewCell cell it auto takes height collectionView cell. let know if you have any confusion.
Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a simple example for one constraint? I have for now used constraints only from Interface Builder.

Comment: Check below link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086054/unable-to-make-outlet-connection-to-a-constraint-in-ib

Comment: I dont have constraints in IB, the whole "UI" is builded only from the code above

Comment: Then just set collectionView frame in tableview cell class  awake from nib

Comment: // create collectionview global in tableView cell class

let SectionCellRowCollection = UICollectionView()

//then add these lines to initialize func

func initialize(){

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        SectionCellRowCollection.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:320, height: 100)
        self.contentView.addSubview(SectionCellRowCollection, collectionViewLayout: layout))
    }