# Advertisement is covering tableview

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I've created a tableview which has an AdMob advertisement banner in the bottom of it. If the user has premium the ad will not be shown, using the code `advertisementBanner.isHidden = true` .

The problem is that when the advertisement is shown I cannot scroll "to the bottom" since it's already scrolled down all the way, but the ad is covering the area.

[image: The image of the tableview]

As you can see I'm not on the bottom, and I cannot scroll down more since I'm already at the "bottom". So my question now is:

Is there any way I can make my "scroll" even longer? Or do you have another alternative I can do to fix this problem? Thanks.

This is the code I've currently:

```
//If no advertisement is shown.
func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError)
{
    advertisementBanner.isHidden = true
}
func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView)
{
    //What should I insert here to "make tableview even longer"
}
```

Comment: Create an outlet of your TableViewHeightConstraint, and when you want to show the add, just reduce the HeightConstraint by your adView height.

Comment: @manishsharma93 How can I do this? I mean, outlet for TableViewHeightConstraint?

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22110084/5084797

Comment: @manishsharma93 Thanks a lot, I managed to create the outlet. Now for the next problem, when the ad is shown I'm adding this one: `TableViewHeightConstraint.constant = 200` But when I run the program it's not getting resized somehow. I've also added the `tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        tableView.updateConstraints()`

Comment: Are you using tableview in a view controller or using UITableViewController?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR ViewController, I might have found a way to figure this out. Lemme check

Comment: Add a view at the bottom (after tableview) and keep its heightConstraint to 0.Now whenever you receive a adView/BannerView in  adViewDidReceiveAd Function, simply just set the height of AddedView to bannerView.height and call LayoutIfNeeded(), We have been using this technique in 50+ applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can move your adView to tableViews footerView.

```
func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError)
{
    tableView.tableFooterView = bannerView
}
func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView)
{
    tableView.tableFooterView = nil
}
```

Comment: Well, the advertisement got placed in a very bad position. But thanks for ur input

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @manishsharma93, I managed to fix my problem.

Instead of adding @IBOutlet to Height, I added it to the bottom constraint.

```
@IBOutlet weak var topConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

And from there I added a constraint to change the space between tableview and navigationcontroller, like this:

```
func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError)
{
    advertisementBanner.isHidden = true //Hiding the ad banner
    topConstraint.constant = 0 //Adding 0 constraint from bottom to tableview

    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    tableView.updateConstraints()
}
```

And then I have this if the ad successfully deployed:

```
func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView)
{
    topConstraint.constant = 100 //Adding 100 "constraints" to bottom

    tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    tableView.updateConstraints()
}
```

I've added "100" to it because the advertisement banner's height is 100.

Answer (score 0):

In your `storyboard` create a view of height 200 and adjust it at bottom of the screen. Set your `Tableview` to its above. Now load `Admob Ad` inside your bottom view. Then Create an outlet for its Height constraint to your swift file. like

```
@IBOutlet var adViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Now adjust your logic like below

```
if (showAd) // depending on your location
{
     adView.isHidden = false;
     adViewHeight.constant = 200;
}  
else { // hide ad
     adView.isHidden = true;
     adViewHeight.constant = 0;
}
```

Comment: I've done this, and everything works perfectly fine. But the only problem I've right now is that, if the ad is NOT shown the "area" where the advertisement is placed is not clickable. How can I fix this? I've ´advertisementBanner.isHidden = true´ but still not clickable. How can I solve this?

Comment: you can set height constraint of your Adview to zero, and also set your view cliptoBounds, View consuming your Clickevent.

Comment: Hmmm, I added adView to 0, and set my clipstoBounds to true. But still does not work :/

Comment: can you share a screenshot now, that how it looks like and where click event is not working?

Comment: I look just like a normal tableview, since the advertisement is hidden

Comment: click event is not working on complete tableview or only for the last item?

Comment: only the 2 last items, since that area is used to be covered by an advertisement

Comment: when ad is shown in that case is it still covering your tableview or your are able to scroll it to end now?

Comment: actually its easy to resolve if I have access to your full code. in this way I am not clear whats the issue.